Changing mantine TextInput error border color
Is there a way to use a selector to change the border color for Mantine V6 TextInput when the error is set?
I can do this by setting the borderColor within the sx object as follows:
<TextInput sx={{ borderColor: error ? 'red': 'green' }} />

but then I have to set the standard borderColor as well.
Using dev tools, I can see that they have a data-invalid class, but I can't seem to find a way to use a selector to target that:
.mantine-188bo4n[data-invalid] {
    color: #fa5252;
    border-color: #fa5252;
}

I know they have the errors property within the styles object but that seems to just target the error text under the input.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Note: I'm using inline styles and the sx prop. I do not want to be using external CSS files.

Targeting the data-invalid attribute directly via sx might not work as expected, but the error prop provides a more direct and reliable way to style the input based on its state.


<TextInput
  error={error}
  classNames={{
    root: error ? 'custom-invalid' : 'custom-valid',  // Apply custom class conditionally
  }}
  sx={{
    '&.custom-invalid': {
      borderColor: 'red',  // Red border for error state
    },
    '&.custom-valid': {
      borderColor: 'green',  // Green border for valid state
    },
  }}
/>




'&[data-invalid="true"]' does not seem to have any effect.

<TextInput
error={error}
classNames={{
root: error ? 'custom-invalid' : 'custom-valid',  // Apply custom class conditionally
}}
sx={{
'&.custom-invalid': {
borderColor: 'red',  // Red border for error state
},
'&.custom-valid': {
borderColor: 'green',  // Green border for valid state
},
}}
/>
Try this one

Your new solution still has the same problem. I'm looking to set just the error styles without needing to define the non error styles.
